# Accessing credentials from username:password@example.com link

Tags: php, apache, http, authentication

I have read the page in [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) related to this, but I am looking to access the `username` and `password`, without specifying the headers before, therefore displaying the form and causing a reload of some kind after.

I want this `username` and `password` passing to be possible to be passed optionally. My goal is to make my administration user depend on these credentials. So, instead of opening `example.com/admin` to login and then get redirected back to `example.com` with administration features displayed, I want to read these credentials and login from those, if they match.

I have `var_dump`'ed `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV`, but requesting with `http://username:password@example.com` do not display them anywhere.

I am running PHP as CGI.

How do I get this done?

### Update:

```
<?php

/*if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
}*/

echo '<pre>';

$user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : null;
$pass = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : null;
var_dump( $user, $pass );

var_dump($_SERVER, $_ENV);

echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the example code I am working with. Colin's suggestion to add the `RewriteRule` did not affect the result.

The thing here is, if that `if` part is commented out, I get `NULL` values for $user and $pass. If I de-comment it, I get proper values.

The `RewriteRule` adds extra header, but is not essential to get the values. It looks like all the magic is with that if.

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of `read URL;  split by ":". [0] being username.replace("http://", ""); [1] being password.remove("@$")`

Comment: The URL is parsed into simple `http://example.com` by the browser before it hits the target, hence cannot be parsed that way.

Comment: @psycketom As is expected. It is the job of the client to take those credentials from the URL, combine them, base64 encode them, and ship them to the server in the `Authorization` header. But you don't get anything in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`?

Comment: I know it's expected to salvage them into `Auth` headers, but yes, I do not get anything in `PHP_AUTH_USER`, even the key is not set.

Comment: @psycketom Are you running PHP as as CGI or are you using mod_php?

Comment: It's running as CGI here.

Comment: @psycketom That's why. That header won't get passed to PHP unfortunately. Try adding this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` which may help push that header to PHP. See if that makes a difference. Then, in PHP: `list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = 
  explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));`

Comment: @psycketom When adding the RewriteRule, you have to add the additional PHP code to actually parse the header as well. The rewrite rule on its own isn't enough. See the second part of my comment. If it works when you uncomment the if, why not use that?

Comment: I saw the second part, the thing is, that without the `if` part, the header from `RewriteRule` is empty - nothing to parse. As for the `if` staying in place, I do not want for basic users to encounter the `HTTP AUTH Form` in case they're not authed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($_SERVER); 
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<hr>';
    echo 'Username: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    echo '<br>Pass: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
}
```

So, with this code in your "auth.php", if you visit http://yourusername:yourpass@yourdomain.com/auth.php
You will be instantly logged with your username and pass provided in URL.
And if you visit the url directly like:
http://yourdomain.com/auth.php a popup will appear asking username and password, and when you enter them, you will again be logged in. Use:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
```

now to get the username and password entered.

Please remember, when you are logged in once, your session remains and to test the password prompt box you need to open a new incognito window by pressing "CTRL + SHIFT + N" and then enter the bare URL yourdomain.com/auth.php